# Split uint16_t variable into 2 uint8_t variables

Tags: c++, casting, binary-data

I am trying to split a 16 bit variable into two 8 bit bytes, but the code I have written doesn't seem to work correctly:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint16_t value = 0x1234;
    uint8_t high = (uint8_t)((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    uint8_t low = (uint8_t)(value & 0x00FF);
    cout<<"higher is "<<hex<<high<<endl;
    cout<<"lower is "<<hex<<low<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When the variables high and low are declared as uint8_t, the result is incorrect. However, when I declare the two variables as uint16_t, the results for them are correct. Please help me understand why this is the case or how I can store the two bytes as uint8_t variables. Thanks!

Comment: Values are corrects, it is the display which is not what you expect ("`char`" display).

Comment: `uint8_t` is usually `unsigned char` which indicates `std::cout` to print a character to the console, cast the result to an int: `static_cast<int>(high)` and `static_cast<int>(low)` and try again.

Comment: @Ruks Thanks for the help! I also found out you can achieve this by simply doing +high and +low when printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the variables high and low are declared as uint8_t, the result is incorrect.

The "result" of the split isn't incorrect.

The output may be other than what you expect because `std::uint8_t` is an alias of a character type (`unsigned char`) and character types are treated differently from other integral types by character streams. You can get the numeric representation by converting to another integer type. Example:

```
std::cout << "higher is " << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned>(high) << '\n';
```

P.S. "High" and "low" are ambiguous in this context. I recommend calling the the most / more significant octet and them least / less significant octet instead. What you call "high" may actually be the byte in a lower memory address (it depends on the system, but this would be the case on x86 systems which are little endian).

Comment: @Eljay `It doesn't look at byte positions` Which is the reason why I recommend against using terms that refer to byte positions (high / low) in favour of terms that refer to significance.